# How to access the log file

Tags: iphone, ipad, crash-reports

I am testing my app "PhotoGallery 2.0" on the ios device. I have enabled stack logs and when the app crashes I receive a message as below on the console.

I want to know how to access the log file `"stack-logs.6963"`, it seems that it is located on the ios device.

> PhotoGallery 2.0(6963) malloc: recording malloc stacks to disk using
>   standard recorder PhotoGallery 2.0(6963) malloc: stack logs being
>   written into
>   /private/var/mobile/Applications/1463221F-0466-4A8D-AA4F-CA8E3B5C2785/tmp/stack-logs.6963.PhotoGallery
>   2.0.index PhotoGallery 2.0(6963) malloc: Please issue: cp /private/var/mobile/Applications/1463221F-0466-4A8D-AA4F-CA8E3B5C2785/tmp/stack-logs.6963.PhotoGallery
>   2.0.KceAMU.link /tmp/

Comment: I couldn't find the logs either.  Don't know why somebody would down vote what seems like a reasonable question to me.  Thanks for asking it.

Comment: Patricia, I don't understand it either.  Things have turned bad recently in SO, as others have pointed out.  Question is reasonable, and has already been helpful to me.  Some people develop feelings of self-importance by giving bad marks to others, but the real problem here is the system should require at least some feedback on *why* the downvote was given.  How do you learn what to avoid doing if it remains unclear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sync your device to your computer, then open XCode, go to Organizer, select Devices, and then Device Logs.

Alternatively, sync your device to your computer, and look in: ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/YourDeviceName/